# LINQ get Highest value and + 1

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I'm newbie to LINQ.
I will like to get know what's the highest value for 'Question Position' and i want increase it by 1 for new Question and save it into database from MVC 4 view.

My db data : (highest position value is 2)

```
====================
Question  | Position
====================
Q1        |     1
Q2        |     2
```

After added new Question : ( increment the highest position (2) + 1 )

```
====================
Question  | Position
====================
Q1        |     1
Q2        |     2
Q3        |     3
```

My Code :

```
var query =
                db.SURV_Question_Model
                .Where(r => r.Question_Survey_ID == viewModel.Survey_ID)
                .GroupBy(r => new { r.Question_Position })
                .Select(grp => grp.OrderByDescending(i => i.Question_Position).FirstOrDefault());
```

After i get the highest value from query, can i do something like below?

```
* int i = query.Question_Position + 1 ???
```

Appreciate your guidance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Max`:

```
var maxId = db.SURV_Question_Model
              .Where(r => r.Question_Survey_ID == viewModel.Survey_ID)
              .Max(x => x.Position);
```

But, if there is not any record it will throw an exception. So, it will be better to change your code as:

```
var maxId = ...Max(x => (int?)x.Position) ?? 0;
```

Comment: @FarhadJabiyev thanks, it works well for me! Now i can increase the maxId + 1 and save into database! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the GorupBy method, this should be enough:

```
var maxId =
    db.SURV_Question_Model
    .Where(r => r.Question_Survey_ID == viewModel.Survey_ID)
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Position)
    .FirstOrDefault());
```

I actually don't know the usage of the where condition, I left there anyway.